How to create json node instead of json property using jackson?
I have a class:
public class Info
{
    private final List<Person> personList;
    private final Map<String, String> personProperties;

    public List<Person> getPersonList()
    {
        return List.copyOf(personList);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getPersonProperties()
    {
        return Map.copyOf(personProperties);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public PrintChequeInfo(
            @JsonProperty("personList") List<Person> personList,
            @JsonProperty("personProperties") Map<String, String> personProperties)
    {
        this.personList= personList;
        this.personProperties= personProperties;
    }
}

So, when i call objectMapper.writeValueAsString(...) on new Info object, i can see kind of this JSON (For example,personList contains one Person object new Person("John","35") and personProperties look like "weight":"70"):
{
  "personList": [
   {
       "name":"John",
       "age" : "35"
   }
   ],
   "personProperties": {
     "weight" : "70"
    }
}

But i need this:
{
  { [
   {
       "name":"John",
       "age" : "35"
   }
   ]},
   {{
     "weight" : "70"
    }}
}

So, I simply need to replace some json property to {}.
Is there a way to do it using jackson just in class definition, without using ObjectNode instances?
It's important, because i need to send my class through http.
I tried to use serializers and create custom serializer for Map and List, but it did not help.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32585217/460557

You cannot do this, becase what you want to get is not a valid json object.

The json example you posted is not valid json. There are unnamed properties inside a json object. What do you actually want to do, how does the json you want to parse actually look?
